# How to split string by space in NetSuite freemarker template?

Tags: javascript, regex, split, netsuite, freemarker

We want to split a string by the space in a NetSuite FreeMarker Template and tried the code as follows:

```
<#list tranline.inventorydetail?split(" ") as paragraph>
    <#if paragraph_index == 0>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="1" >${showIndex}</td>
            <td colspan="4">${tranline.item}</td>
            <td align="left" colspan="6">${tranline.description}</td>
            <td align="right" colspan="2">${tranline.quantityordered}</td>
            <td align="right" colspan="2">${tranline.quantityremaining}</td>
            <td align="right" colspan="2">${tranline.quantity}</td>
            <td align="left" colspan="4">${paragraph?keep_before(",")}</td>
          </tr>
     <#else>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="1" ></td>
            <td colspan="4"></td>
            <td align="left" colspan="6"></td>
            <td align="right" colspan="2"></td>
            <td align="right" colspan="2"></td>
            <td align="right" colspan="2"></td>
            <td align="left" colspan="4">${paragraph?keep_before(",")}</td>
          </tr>
      </#if> 
</#list>
```

But it doesn't take effect.

Following methods also don't split the string into an array by space:

```
<#list tranline.inventorydetail?split("\\s+") as paragraph>
<#list tranline.inventorydetail?split("\s+") as paragraph>
<#list tranline.inventorydetail?split("&nbsp;") as paragraph>
```

Does anyone know how to split a string in NetSuite FreeeMarker Template by space?

Comment: Try `split(/\s+/)`

Comment: It shows:   Syntax error in template "template" in line 297, column 47:
Encountered "/", but was expecting one of:
<STRING_LITERAL>
<RAW_STRING>
"false"
"true"
<INTEGER>
<DECIMAL>
"."
"+"
"-"
"!"
"["
"("
")"
"{"
<ID>

Comment: split(" ", 'r') try this

Comment: It doesn't take effect as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can split a string at white-space with `somestring?word_list`. Consecutive white-space characters will count as a single separator. Note that it only considers there characters as white-space: space, `\t`, `\n`, `\r` `\f` (which is usually enough).

You could also use `?split(r'\s+', 'r')`, which recognizes all kind of UNICODE white-space as separator, however, it also has a glitch where for a 0 length string it returns `[""]` instead of `[]` (because that's how Java `Pattern.split` behaves).